# Word for the result of a magic spell

Tags: single-word-requests

If a wizard casts a fireball spell, a fireball is created. If a wizard casts a flight spell, the target gains the ability to fly. In both cases, a particular result has occurred due to the casting of the spell.

What is the word for this result (or in other words, what is a term that can be used to refer to both the fireball and flight ability and denotes that they are the result of a spell being cast)?

Comment: The result of a magic spell is plain old magic, right?

Comment: Magic effect? I think that's what some games use.

Comment: How about "spellbound"?

Comment: When dealing with imaginary events, it's useful to find out what constraints have been placed on the imagination. For instance, is there a classification of spells in your epistemology? Is there variation in power from spell to spell? What does it depend on? Are all spellcasters human, or are there other kinds of powers? Etc... ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If one wants to isolate the *act* of incantation from the *result* of the incantation *[enchantment](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/enchantment)* works well:

> noun
>
> 2 The state of being under a spell; magic:

Answer (score 4):

*[Spell](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/spell#spell-2)* denotes both the *incantation* and the *enchantment* caused by the incantation:

> noun
>
> 1.0 A form of words used as a magical charm or incantation:
>
> 1.1 A state of enchantment caused by a magic spell:
>
> *ODO*

Answer (score 3):

You could, conceivably, refer to both the Magick and its effects as “**The Work**” i.e., “*after years of exacting preparation The Work had been perfected and had taken its prophesied effect*.”

> **Work**
>
> **3 c**. The action or effect of an agency. see The Free Dictionary [work](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/work)

Comment: Yes and there is also a more specific word: [*spellwork*.](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Spellwork)

Comment: @ermanen - true. I was making an allusion to the Magnus Opus of the alchemists.